# Need Help Displaying The Name Instead of a GUID in a DataTable in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I need some help displaying the name instead of a GUID inside a DataTable in MVC 5.

I implemented the DataTable by following this tutorial: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-crud-operation-with-jquery-datatables-in-asp-net-mvc-5-for-beginners/

I am trying to show the names for a Municipal Region, Municipality and Client Status. It shows perfectly fine inside my details view model, however it displays the GUID in the DataTable. I have spent days trying to figure this out to no avail.

Here is the code for the DataTable in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Get([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestModel, ClientsAdvancedSearchViewModel searchViewModel)
    {
        IQueryable<Client> query = DbContext.Clients;
        var totalCount = query.Count();

        // searching and sorting
        query = SearchClients(requestModel, searchViewModel, query);
        var filteredCount = query.Count();

        // Paging
        query = query.Skip(requestModel.Start).Take(requestModel.Length);

        var data = query.Select(client => new
        {
            ClientIdentifier = client.ClientIdentifier,
            CompanyName = client.CompanyName,
            ClientContactPerson = client.ClientContactPerson,
            ClientEmail = client.ClientEmail,
            ClientTel = client.ClientTel,
            Consultant = client.Consultant,
            Town = client.Town,
            Suburb = client.Suburb,
            MunicipalRegionID = client.MunicipalRegionID,
            MunicipalityID = client.MunicipalityID,
            ClientStatusID = client.ClientStatusID,
        }).ToList();

        return Json(new DataTablesResponse(requestModel.Draw, data, filteredCount, totalCount), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

And here is the code for my client class:

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public System.Guid ClientIdentifier { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string SiteName { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public string Consultant { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }

    public string ClientInformation { get; set; }

    public string ClientContactPerson { get; set; }

    public string ClientEmail { get; set; }

    public string ClientTel { get; set; }

    public string ClientAddress { get; set; }

    public string GPSCoordinates { get; set; }

    public string Town { get; set; }

    public string Suburb { get; set; }

    public System.Guid MunicipalRegionID { get; set; }

    public System.Guid MunicipalityID { get; set; }

    public System.Guid ClientStatusID { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string LastEditedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateLastEdited { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the code for my Municipal Region Class:

```
public class MunicipalRegion
{
    [Key]
    public System.Guid MunicipalRegionIdentifier { get; set; }

    public string MunicipalRegionName { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string LastEditedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateLastEdited { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code for my Municipality Class:

```
public class Municipality
{
    [Key]
    public System.Guid MunicipalityIdentifier { get; set; }

    public string MunicipalityName { get; set; }

    public System.Guid MunicipalRegionID { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string LastEditedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateLastEdited { get; set; }
```

Here is the code for my Client Status Class:

```
public class ClientStatus
{
    [Key]
    public System.Guid ClientStatusIdentifier { get; set; }

    public string ClientStatusName { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string LastEditedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateLastEdited { get; set; }
}
```

Help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but it sounds like you are trying to hide the key fields from generated views.  This can be accomplished adding the following annotation.

`[Display(AutoGenerateField=false)]`

---

Ok, I see what you are trying to do now.  The main problem is your classes are not set up correctly.  From a database perspective they are correct but from a class perspective, they won't return what you want.

You need to set up your classes as follows

**Client Class**

```
public Client()
        {
            Municipality = new Municipality();
            Status = new ClientStatus();            
        }

        [Key]
        public System.Guid ClientIdentifier { get; set; }

        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        public string SiteName { get; set; }

        public string Consultant { get; set; }

        public string Comments { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }

        public string ClientInformation { get; set; }

        public string ClientContactPerson { get; set; }

        public string ClientEmail { get; set; }

        public string ClientTel { get; set; }

        public string ClientAddress { get; set; }

        public string GPSCoordinates { get; set; }

        public string Town { get; set; }

        public string Suburb { get; set; }

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }

        public string LastEditedBy { get; set; }

        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateLastEdited { get; set; }

        // Create Forign Key Connections

        public Municipality Municipality { get; set; }

        public ClientStatus Status { get; set; }

    }
```

**Municipality Class**

```
public class Municipality
{
    public Municipality() {
        MunicipalRegion = new MunicipalRegion();
    }

    [Key]
    public System.Guid MunicipalityIdentifier {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string MunicipalityName { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated { get; set; }

    public string LastEditedBy { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateLastEdited { get; set; }

    public MunicipalRegion MunicipalRegion { get; set; }

}
```

This will allow you to produce output using something similar to

```
        var data = clients.Select(cl => new
        {
            ClientIdentifier = cl.ClientIdentifier,
            CompanyName = cl.CompanyName,
            MunicipalRegion = cl.Municipality.MunicipalityName,
            Status = cl.Status.ClientStatusName
        });
```

Comment: Hi Shawn. Apologies, I may have not been clear enough in the question, Here is a screenshot of my table. As you can see, it displays uniqueidentifiers for the Municipal Region and the Municipality. I need to display the names for the Municipal region and Municipality which is stored in their own tables and linked to the Client table. https://i.imgur.com/mVURXsb.png